# How to summarize the values of duplicates in an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for my English.

Hello, I can not solve the problem, help please. There is an array:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'player_id' => '1',
        'count_goals' => (int) 1
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'player_id' => '2',
        'count_goals' => (int) 1
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'player_id' => '1',
        'count_goals' => (int) 1
    )
)
```

The result should be:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'player_id' => '1',
        'count_goals' => (int) 1
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'player_id' => '2',
        'count_goals' => (int) 1
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'player_id' => '1',
        'count_goals' => (int) 1
    )
)
```

if the player_id does not have a unique number in the array, then increase its count_goals by 1.

Comment: I assume you want to sum the goals for each player? :)

Comment: @Robert You correctly understood)

Comment: @Alex shouldn't the result block show the sum of the goals? right  now both  code blocks show the same array?

Comment: I've added an answer, but i'm not sure what you meant with: `if the player_id does not have a unique number in the array, then increase its count_goals by 1.` As the count_goals is set ? My guess is that just want to increase it with the number from the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to group and sum:

```
$result = [];
foreach ($input as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['player_id']])) {
        $result[$row['player_id']] = 0;
    }
    $result[$row['player_id']] += $result[$row['count_goals']];
}
```

This will give you an array like:

```
[
   1 => 2, // player_id => sum of count_goals
   2 => 1,
]
```

Then you can convert that back to an associative array if needed.

```
$finalResult = [];
foreach ($result as $playerId => $sumOfGoals) {
     $finalResult[] = [
         'player_id' => $playerId,
         'count_goals' => $sumOfGoals,
     ];
}

print_r($finalResult);
```